# Problem with designing finite state machine

Tags: state-machines

I'm learning now finite state machines and I'm stuck with this exercise from a book "Digital Design and Computer Architecture" by David and Sarah Harris:

[image]

First I tried to solve it without looking at the answer. My idea was to store An-1 (previous value of A) in FSM's current state. So there is 2 possible states of FSM: S0 (if An-1 == 0) and S1 (An-1 == 1).
Here's my state transition diagram (note all arrows with A lead to S1 state and arrows with A bar lead to S0):

[image]

And here is state transition table with equations for S' (next state of FSM) and Z (output) below it:

[image]

Then I wired this FSM in Logic Circuit program. What it looks like:
[image]

And my solution seems to work. I thought it is the best solution. But then I checked the answer and there is another solution (screens below). They use 4 states, but I can't understand what are these states for? How does it work? I've built this circuit too and it seems to work in similar way as mine. But then I noticed, that my circuit doesn't have feedback part. So it is not finite state machine and my solution wrong?
In short, I have 2 questions:

1. Is my solution trash or not?
2. What are these 4 states of FSM in solution and what is the main idea of it?
   [image]

[image]

Comment: I can't edit my post, so I'm gonna write it here. First of all, hello!

Comment: It is a bit of a stretch to call this a state machine at all. Your solution can (I'm not checking fine details) satisfy the wording of the problem statement; at a glance it looks fine to me.

Comment: Indeed, the problem set author confused themselves.  This isn't a state machine so much as a single register delay.  The problem is quite clearly that of a Mealy machine (outputs depending on state and inputs), having four states would suggest they got confused and started to build a Moore machine producing a cycle-delayed version of the requested output, but if the gate diagram given is the official solution it's actually still Mealy.  **Teacher fail** - but with the right attitudes this can lead to a discussion better than the intended lesson.  With the wrong ones, ouch!

Comment: And indeed the student's solution would convert into a cycle delayed version, simply by registering Z ... giving better timings guaranteed glitch free, than the book solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the erroneous official solution is not a technical problem but rather something the student needs to discuss with their teacher.  The only answer that could really be provided here is that "the official solution is wrong" - speculating what the author of that solution was thinking isn't really on topic, or of any use.

Comment: Can you provide some solutions to this exercise then, please?